# Saving file Multiple Times Fails with A generic error occurred in GDI+. Exception

Tags: c#, .net, gdi

Below is the offending code. The Stream is coming from a HttpPostedFile. Tested in local is fine. 
Tested online also fine for the first time when overwriting. The exception is only thrown when you try to overwrite the file multiple times. Eg. Upload then Re-upload Any insights?

```
    public void ResizeFromStream(string ImageSavePath, int MaxSideSize, Stream Buffer)
    {   
        int intNewWidth;
        int intNewHeight;
        System.Drawing.Image imgInput = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Buffer);

        //Determine image format 
        ImageFormat fmtImageFormat = imgInput.RawFormat;

        //get image original width and height 
        int intOldWidth = imgInput.Width;
        int intOldHeight = imgInput.Height;

        //determine if landscape or portrait 
        int intMaxSide;

        if (intOldWidth >= intOldHeight)
        {
            intMaxSide = intOldWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            intMaxSide = intOldHeight;
        }

        Bitmap bmpResized = null;
        if (intMaxSide > MaxSideSize)
        {
            //set new width and height 
            double dblCoef = MaxSideSize / (double)intMaxSide;
            intNewWidth = Convert.ToInt32(dblCoef * intOldWidth);
            intNewHeight = Convert.ToInt32(dblCoef * intOldHeight);

            bmpResized = new Bitmap(imgInput, intNewWidth, intNewHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            intNewWidth = intOldWidth;
            intNewHeight = intOldHeight;
            bmpResized = new Bitmap(Buffer);
        }

        //save bitmap to disk
        bmpResized.Save(ImageSavePath, fmtImageFormat);

        //release used resources 
        imgInput.Dispose();
        bmpResized.Dispose();
        Buffer.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: The file is probably locked because someone started downloading it. Try deleting the file before doing the save - if I'm right, it will fail as well.

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly right but it set me on the right path. Turns out, right after this function calls, I have another function that opens the file but never disposes of the resources hence causing the 2nd call to fail. Strange thing is that the exact same code worked in local without any problems though....

Comment: Well, it happens. Servers tend to be a lot more nitpicky, and full IIS is a bit stricter than IIS Express. That's why you need a staging area as close to the production configs as possible :)

Comment: And there's another lesson here - try to use `using` when it makes sense, and `try ... finally` whenever you're releasing any resources. It helps a lot in building reliable applications :)